# How can for_loop be reduced in 3D Grid Map Search?

Tags: c#

To navigate all the maps in the 3D grid map(or 3D Matrix), I must perform for_loop on the X, Y, and Z coordinates, respectively.

E.g,

> `for (traveling all X)
>       for (traveling all Y)
>        for (traveling all Z)
>           blah blah....`

What I want is,
**- How can I reduce the above 3 nested for loops?**

Comment: I can't tell because it depends on your problem. you may want to look for a way to run them in parallel.

Comment: I got your word. In my case, I do not think there's a way to reduce that 3 nested for_loop. Thank you for your reply.